# Log information from same code to different destinations

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

I have some class which logs information and it used in two different locations.

```
class SomeClass: ISomeClass {
    private ILogger _logger = Log.GetLogger();
    public void Action() {
        _logger.Log("Action started");
        //....
    }
}

class OneUsage {
    ILogger _logger = Logger.GetLogger();
    public OneUsage(ISomeClass someClass) {
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }
    public OtherAction() {
        _logger.Log("Other action started");
        someClass.Action();
    }
}

class SecondUsage {
    ILogger _logger = Logger.GetLogger();
    public SecondUsage(ISomeClass someClass) {
        this.someClass = someClass;
    }
    public OtherAction() {
        _logger.Log("Second Other action started");
        someClass.Action();
    }
}
```

And I need to write logs from OneUsage to one place and from SecondUsage to other place.
E.g. when I call

```
oneUsage.OtherAction(); // I want logs to be written to DB
```

And when I call

```
secondUsage.OtherAction // I want logging to some file
```

All this calls may happened at the same time on same running application.

Can I configure Log4net in some way to make this happen?
Or may be there is some other way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The log4net way of doing this is, to configure several loggers and resolve them by name. Each logger contains one or more appenders (ConsoleAppender, RollingFileAppender, etc.). By resolving the correct logger in your component you can define the output channel.

Configuration (see [Loggers in Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#Loggers))

```
<logger name="LoggerOne">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="LoggerTow">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="AnyCustomAppender" />
</logger>
```

Resolving (see [Logger hierarchy in Introduction](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html#Logger_hierarchy))

```
class OneUsage {
    ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerOne");
    _logger.Log("Message to console.");
}

class SecondUsage {
    ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerTwo");
    _logger.Log("Message custom logging output.");
}
```

Please let me know, if this helps.

Comment: Hm, but I need ability to resolve appender from outer class, say from call site of OneUsage.
    //setup proper logger
    oneUsage.OtherAction(); // than all logs goes to setuped line above place

Comment: Can you please explain this with more details and probably a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a logger in your SomeClass, instead pass the loggers from your calling classes as a parameter to someclass.

If your someclass-Instances are always the same, pass the logger to every method, if you have differnt instances, pass the logger to the constructor.

Comment: But I don't want to pollute my API with logging details. And I ask maybe there is some common solution to this kinds of problems.

Comment: in appender-configuration you can work with filters, but what do you want to filter? you need to know the calling class, i don't think this is possible... If, in this "special" class, you have to use "parent" logging configuration, pass the "parent" logger into the class instead of having a logger in the class itself.